# Get client's IP address in Sinatra?

Tags: ip-address, sinatra

This is a really simple question, but I cannot find any mention of this, anywhere..

How do I get the client's IP address from in Sinatra?

```
get '/' do
    "Your IP address is #{....}"
end
```

Comment: Err, oh, it's in `@env['REMOTE_ADDR']` - I had checked the `@env.inspect` output by searching for "127.0.0.1", but it was showing the IPv6 `::1` address so I missed it... Anyone feel free to post that so I can accept it without the 48-hour wait.. (free rep! :P)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Sinatra provides a [`request` object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object), which is the interface to the client request data that you should be using.

Using `request.ip` is the preferred method to find the client's IP address:

```
get '/' do
  "Your IP address is #{request.ip}"
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Request#ip` method comes from Rack, not from Sinatra.

Answer (score 18):

I was coming to post the answer anyway.. so:

```
get '/' do
"Your IP address is #{ @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] }"
end
```

Sinatra uses the [**Rack::Request** API](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html), so you can use a lot of things available in it.
Also a link to the  [**Sinatra** doc's](http://www.sinatrarb.com/api/index.html).

Comment: Hm, the Rack::Request API mentions an `ip` method, which handles the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` as well, is there a way to call this from Sinatra?

Comment: you should be able to just do #{ @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] }   I have never tested this though, so I'm not positive.

Comment: you can do request.ip directly, as well.  get "/" do; "your IP: #{request.ip}"; end

Comment: see: https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L315 ... very risky approach here