# How can I always log the IP with logger?

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get client’s IP address in Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319331/get-clients-ip-address-in-sinatra)

I'm using Sinatra with Apache and Passenger.

I'm currently using the following logger in my `config.ru`:

```
LOGGER = Logger.new("logs/sinatra.log")
```

I can log things in my app using:

```
LOGGER.error "Log msg"
```

An example log entry looks like this:

```
E, [2013-01-18T19:43:41.857146 #19412] ERROR -- : Log msg
```

How can I put the IP of the current user into the log, so it might look like this:

```
E, [2013-01-18T19:43:41.857146 #19412] ERROR -- : <127.0.0.1> Log msg
```

I could write:

```
LOGGER.error "<#{request.ip}> Log msg"
```

But, I want to have it on every log message, so always prepending the IP manually seems to be the wrong way. How can the `LOGGER` be configured to parse the `request.ip` automatically and to put it into the log?

---

I tried it the following way as suggested in some answers:

configure.ru:

```
configure do
    LOGGER = Logger.new("logs/sinatra.log")
    original_formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
    LOGGER.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
        original_formatter.call(severity, datetime, progname, "#{ip} #{msg.dump}")
    }
end
```

app.rb:

```
helpers do
    def ip
        request.ip
    end
end

get '/' do
    LOGGER.info 'test'
end
```

This is the result:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ip' for #<Rack::Builder:0x00000001821c60>
```

---

**Update** Based on theTinMan's answer I came up with the following helper:

```
helpers do
    def log(call,msg = '')
        severity = Logger.const_get(call.upcase)
        return if LOGGER.level > severity

        msg = yield if block_given?
        LOGGER.send(call, "<#{request.ip}> #{msg}")
    end
end
```

So I can do this:

```
log :info, 'msg'
log(:debug) { very.expensive.operation }
```

This looks like the solution I wanted. Is there room for improvement?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the IP available is valid, because of proxies, NAT, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple and Ideal Logging in Sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644753/simple-and-ideal-logging-in-sinatra), [Sinatra Logger for Web Service Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8716595/128421), [Logging in Sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5995854/128421) and [Get client's IP address in Sinatra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319331/get-clients-ip-address-in-sinatra)

Comment: @theTinMan but some ip address must be there, since something triggered a request. that should be logged. And in the threads you linked I see no way to have the ip outputted by default.

Comment: The threads linked are a combination of various ways to use LOGGER, and how to get `request.ip`. From those you can easily put together a solution. You can't expect a custom-tailored answer.

Comment: Additional useful answers are: [Use Rack::CommonLogger in Sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239240/use-rackcommonlogger-in-sinatra) and [Where does RACK log to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366352/where-does-rack-log-to).

Comment: Change `def log(call,msg = '')` to `def log(call=:info, msg = '')` to default to `:info` level. I'd consider reversing the order of the parameters, because you *ALWAYS* want a message and defaulting to `:info` is reasonable. I see the value in using a block to return the message though, so it's a mixed-bag.

Comment: Some address would be there, but it could be wildly different than the address the request actually came from, especially when people are deliberately trying to hide their IP.

Comment: I don't see this being a duplicate, since the question is not about how to get the ip address, but how to always log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Simple and Ideal Logging in Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644753/simple-and-ideal-logging-in-sinatra?rq=1)":

I tend to use something like:

```
require 'sinatra'
use Rack::Logger

def log(msg)
  logger.info('%s: %s' % [request.ip, msg])
end

get '/' do
  log("Request for '/'")
  '<html><body>psych</body></html>'
end
```

Which outputs:

```
I, [2013-01-18T23:39:42.049072 #81011]  INFO -- : 127.0.0.1: Request for '/'
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2013 23:39:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 0.0034
```

I could sub-class Logger, or to patch it, but I prefer wrapping the logger call in a local method. We use that in several apps at work, and it works nicely.

Comment: where do these logs go to? Can this be a seperate logfile (`logs/sinatra.log`) besides of the regular output? and I would have to define a method for each severity (`info error warn` etc) or to make the method accept two arguments (severity + msg), so something like `log(:info,'msg')` would work ... okey, is an idea.

Comment: added a helper based on your answer to my question. do you see room for improvement?

Answer (score -1):

You can override the formatter for Logger. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html for an example.
You can create a sinatra helper method to return the request IP, so that it can be called from the formatter proc.

Comment: tried it, but not working (updated my question). can you give a working example?